# How do I get a signedUrl from gcs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

Working with cloud functions to return a list of signedUrls for my images.  Right now I get the error `SigningError: Cannot sign data without`client_email`.`

I tried doing just `const storage = new Storage();` without adding the config object but I still get the same error.  I even tried:

```
const storage = new Storage({ 
  projectId: projectId,
  keyFilename:'./cert.json' //my service account file
});
```

But from this I get nothing, not even an error message.  My function just returns an empty array `[]`

How do I configure things so that I can get back signed urls?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');    
import * as _ from 'lodash'
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const projectId = 'myProject';
const storage = new Storage({ 
  projectId: projectId,
});

export const getPublicURLS = async()=>{
  let bucketName='myBucket.appspot.com'
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles({prefix:'myTestPrefix'});
  files.shift(); //remove the folder object
  let list = await _.map(files, (file)=>{
    return file.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-17-2025'
    }).then(results => {
      console.log(results);
      const url = results[0];
      return url;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
  })
  return list;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're not dealing with promises correctly. map() doesn't return a single promise that you can await.

Comment: You need a service account to be able to do this